# audio streamming over ip one encoder multiple decoder

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, encoder, decoder

My radio stations are each in a city. I want to connect them via the Internet and manage them from one place. Is there any device that can be used other than a computer?
That is, like an encoder and decoder, but use more than one decoder?

Comment: Yes, there are purpose-built boxes for this but ultimately they're basically all little Linux boxes.  Why don't you want to use a computer?

Comment: More than 10 stations cost us a lot

Comment: I can't think of a cheaper way to do this than via a computer.  Far more expensive for the Barix boxes and what not, and you don't get flexibility that way.